# Map of API name and value pair..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

I want to create a map of apiname and value pair..please help...
i want record value...like if apiname of opportunity field is name..then i want record value..ie opportunity name...

for eg

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
Opportunity opp=[Select id,name,accountId from Opportunity];
 Map<String,string> valueMap=new Map<String,String>();

    for(opportunity o:opp)
           {
                for(String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet())
                {
                    **valueMap.put(fieldName,o);**
                }

           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, having re-read the question...

You can use get with the fieldname on the sObject, e.g.

```
Opportunity opp=[Select id,name,accountId from Opportunity limit 1];
System.debug(opp.get('name'));
```

So in your example I think you want

```
valueMap.put(fieldName, o.get(fieldName));
```

Comment: thanks for replying doug..but i want record value...like if apiname of opportunity field is name..then i want record value..ie opportunity name...

Comment: I have edited the answer - does this help?

Comment: great..that's perfect...i wanted this exactly ...great..thanks..

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
Opportunity opp = [Select id,name,accountId from Opportunity];
Map<String,String> valueMap = new Map<String,String>();

for ( Opportunity o : opp ) {
    for ( String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet() ) {
        valueMap.put(fieldName, o.get(fieldName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have already accepted an answer, but I think there is a flaw in your example code, if you have more than one opportunity in the `opp` list your will end up with only key/value pairs in the `valueMap` of the last opportunity in the list.

For example if you have 2 opportunities {opp1(Name="Greg"), opp2(Name="Tom")} in the list, your Map will look like {Name=>"Tom"}

Another point is that Apex SObjects already have *Map* methods for accessing the values on the object. I refer to the [SObject Methods Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm). There are `get` and `put` methods that would accomplish everything your key value Map does. Both other answers are using these methods to populate the valueMap

Comment: It's a good point, and it would be interesting to understand what the purpose of the code actually is. Also the query is only returning id, name, accountid from the opportunity so most of the opportunity data won't be there to query. Still I think the answer stands as "how can I generically get sObject values"

Comment: good point daniel... actually i wont get more than 1 opportunity...as my query will have where clause      Opportunity opp = [Select id,name,accountId from Opportunity where id=:oppid];'  anyways thanks for the point..